# Rollback/Delete message from queue by producer before receiving it

Tags: jms, hornetq

A producer is sending many messages to the queue.Now queue has theses messages stored.So before consuming these messages from consumer, if producer wants to delete some messages on queue which he sent it by mistake & he dont want receiver shoul receive this message.how can i achieve this. or any other suggestion,thnx

Answer (score 2):

You should keep your session as transacted, and at the end either commit or rollback.

if you meant to commit and now you need to rollback, then you have a serious design problem with your application which you should review. Doing anything beyond that will require your application to have a database to deal with receives and ignore them, but if you can use a database for that you would have performance issues on accessing data in a sync manner.

Comment: nope ...i am accessing data in asynchronous  manner.....how would I delete msg from queue using hornetq inbuilt functionality....i hope u got the point...thnx...

Comment: I think you're having a misconception on what's a message system.
A message system it's not a database where you can add and delete stuff based on your data. It's fire and forget.
The fact that you actually need to delete messages tells me you have architectural problems.

on a Async System you can use a transaction to determine if you can commit the message or not....

Mixing DB concepts on a message system is a recipe for a big disaster! be careful!

Comment: the only concepts you have on a message system are:
Send
Consume / ACK
And you can use transactions on sending and ACK.

Comment: in any case, you can create a consumer with a filter, and ack all the messages that match your filter. set the properties accordingly to your message on producing so you can filter them...

but again.. that's a recipe for disasters.. it's not a database.. a message system is optimized for fifo delivery, not a database!

Comment: Take a look on Infinispan BTW. You would have more success on adding and delete stuff. it appears to me that's what you actually need.

Comment: thnx for the suggetion clebart ,I am also thinking the same....can u plz elaborate about infispan in brief...

Comment: Infinispan is a cache system, where you can act like a database. you can store, and delete messages in a fast manner.  Take a look a these Cache systems, they are quite useful

Comment: I deserve at least a vote here :) I'm trying to get beyond 2000 points :P

Comment: well.. that's another question.. but on Stack Overflow you can either accept an answer, vote for an answer or vote for anything. YOu just press the arrow up on the answer or the accept answer

Answer (score 0):

One possible way: If the producer knows id of the message to be deleted, then it can just receive that message to remove that message from a queue. But this is not guaranteed to remove the message as consumer might have already received the message before producer realizes the mistake.

Comment: ya thnx for the suggestion shashi, we can do this programmatically but Is there any inbuilt functionality available in jms or hornetq to delete msg from queue??

Comment: Not JMS for sure. I am not aware of HornetQ though. In general terms the above is the way to delete message from a queue.

Comment: ya im i actually want to delete message but using hornetq inbuilt functionality because im using JBOSS server....anyways thnx for the help shahshi....:)